# Difference between .dll and .exe?

Tags: windows, dll, exe

I want to know the exact difference between the dll and exe file.

Comment: You should add some context here:
Are you a beginner
Are you looking a some kind of deep technical specification of the PE stuff
Or something else

Comment: It is true I am a beginner. It is a interview-question as tagged.

Comment: More importantly, this is a duplicate **including** one (deleted) by sakthivignesh...

Answer (score 82, accepted):

EXE:

1. It's a executable file
2. When loading an executable, no export is called, but only the module entry point.
3. When a system launches new executable, a new process is created
4. The entry thread is called in context of main thread of that process.

DLL:

1. It's a Dynamic Link Library
2. There are multiple exported symbols.
3. The system loads a DLL into the context of an existing process.

For More Details: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Interviews/Answer/Answers.aspxQuestionId=1431&MajorCategoryId=1&MinorCategoryId=1
http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_is_the_difference_between_an_EXE_and_a_DLL

Reference: http://www.dotnetspider.com/forum/34260-What-difference-between-dll-exe.aspx

Comment: The system loads a DLL into an existing PROCESS, not thread. Every DLL in a process can get a notification when a thread starts or stops, via a `LibMain` function.

Comment: Your points 1 and 2 are not 100% correct. 

Since you can use LoadLibraryEx on an exe or dll that means you can use the GetProcAddress to load an entry point from an exe or a dll.

So in that regard both exe and dll files can be dynamically linked and can have any number of entry points.

Answer (score 160):

I don't know why everybody is answering this question in context of .NET. The question was a general one and didn't mention .NET anywhere.

Well, the major differences are:

**EXE**

1. An exe always runs in its own address space i.e., It is a separate process.
2. The purpose of an EXE is to launch a separate application of its own.

**DLL**

1. A dll always needs a host exe to run. i.e., it can never run in its own address space.
2. The purpose of a DLL is to have a collection of methods/classes which can be re-used from some other application.
3. DLL is Microsoft's implementation of a shared library.

The file format of DLL and exe is essentially the same. Windows recognizes the difference between DLL and EXE through PE Header in the file. For details of PE Header, [You can have a look at this Article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809762.aspx)

Comment: So, if you wanted you coudl rename and edit the header of the fikle to turn a dll into an exe and vice versa?

Comment: @RCIX: I doubt that is possible?

Comment: It's most likely not possible - see [kichik's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4266184/119527) below.

Answer (score 31):

The difference is that an EXE has an entry point, a "main" method that will run on execution.

The code within a DLL needs to be called from another application.

Comment: This is misloading, it implies that DLLs don't have entry points. DLLs may have a DLLMain entry point which is called when (among other things) the DLL is loaded into the process

Answer (score 31):

There are a few more differences regarding the structure you could mention.

1. Both DLL and EXE share the same file structure - Portable Executable, or PE. To differentiate between the two, one can look in the `Characteristics` member of `IMAGE_FILE_HEADER` inside `IMAGE_NT_HEADERS`. For a DLL, it has the `IMAGE_FILE_DLL` (0x2000) flag turned on. For a EXE it's the `IMAGE_FILE_EXECUTABLE_IMAGE` (0x2) flag.
2. PE files consist of some headers and a number of sections. There's usually a section for code, a section for data, a section listing imported functions and a section for resources. Some sections may contain more than one thing. The header also describes a list of data directories that are located in the sections. Those data directories are what enables Windows to find what it needs in the PE. But one type of data directory that an EXE will never have (unless you're building a frankenstein EXE) is the export directory. This is where DLL files have a list of functions they export and can be used by other EXE or DLL files. On the other side, each DLL and EXE has an import directory where it lists the functions and DLL files it requires to run.
3. Also in the PE headers (`IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER`) is the `ImageBase` member. It specifies the virtual address at which the PE assumes it will be loaded. If it is loaded at another address, some pointers could point to the wrong memory. As EXE files are amongst the first to be loaded into their new address space, the Windows loader can assure a constant load address and that's usually 0x00400000. That luxury doesn't exist for a DLL. Two DLL files loaded into the same process can request the same address. This is why a DLL has another data directory called Base Relocation Directory that usually resides in its own section - `.reloc`. This directory contains a list of places in the DLL that need to be rebased/patched so they'll point to the right memory. Most EXE files don't have this directory, but some old compilers do generate them.

You can read more on this topic @ [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809762.aspx).

Comment: 1. As those are flags, both can be set at once. 2. As you said, it's possible but vanishingly unlikely. 3. ASLR will relocate the exe too, if it can. So yes, even an exe can have relocations. All in all, EXEs which are DLLs are *possible but rare*.

Answer (score 26):

This answer was a little more detailed than I thought but read it through.

**DLL:**
In most cases, a DLL file is a *library*. There are a couple of types of libraries, dynamic and static - [read about the difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140061/when-to-use-dynamic-vs-static-libraries).  DLL stands for [dynamic link **library**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic-link_library) which tells us that it's a *part* of the program but **not** the whole thing. It's made of reusable software components ([library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_%28computing%29)) which  you could use for *more than a single program*. Bear in mind that it's always possible to use the library source code in many applications using copy-paste, but the idea of a DLL/Static Library is that you could update the code of a library and at the same time update all the applications using it - without compiling.

**For example:**
Imagine you're creating a [Windows GUI component](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_user_interface) like a ***Button***. In most cases you'd want to re-use the code you've written because it's a complex but a *common* component - You want many applications to use it but you don't want to give them the source code You can't copy-paste the code for the button in every program, so you decide you want to create a [DL-Library  (DLL)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_%28computing%29).

This *"button"* library is required by **EXE**cutables to run, and without it they will not run because they don't know how to create the button, only how to talk to it.

Likewise, a DLL cannot be executed - run, because it's only a part of the program but doesn't have the information required to create a ["process"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29).

**EXE:**
An executable is *the program*. It knows how to create a [process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29) and how to talk to the DLL. It *needs* the DLL to create a button, and without it the application doesn't run - ERROR.

hope this  helps....

Comment: In the .NET development world, when you're importing things from other modules, like for example, in C# `using SomeClassFromALibrary`, that library is linked to the project via a DLL? Just trying to see if I'm understanding correctly

Comment: You normally use the keyword `using` for namespaces, not classes. Exception is for `using static` available from c# 6 which imports all static members present in the class specified([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-static)). The `using` keyword gives a promise to the compiler that at runtime there will be a library containing that _namespace_. The library is not linked to the project via that DLL, the DLL is the library that is linked to the project(assembly). That DLL contains all the code that was promised in compile time.

Answer (score 18):

Both DLL and EXE are [Portable Executable(PE) Formats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable)

A **[Dynamic-link library (DLL)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic-link_library)** is a library and therefore can not be executed directly. If you try to run it you will get an error about a missing entry point. It needs an entry point (main function) to get executed, that entry point can be any application or exe. DLL binding occurs at run-time. That is why its called "Dynamic Link" library.

An **[Executable (EXE)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EXE)** is a program that can be executed. It has its own entry point. A flag inside the PE header indicates which type of file it is (irrelevant of file extension). The PE header has a field where the entry point for the program resides. In DLLs it isn't used (or at least not as an entry point).

There are many [software](http://www.heaventools.com/PE-file-header_viewer.htm) available to check header information. The only difference causing both to work differently is the bit in header as shown in below diagram.

> [image: header]

EXE file has only single main entry means it is isolated application, when a system launches exe, a new process is created while DLLs have many entry points so when application use it no new process started, DLL can be reused and versioned. DLL reduces storage space as different programs can use the same dll.

Comment: You say "A flag inside the PE header indicates which type of file it is (irrelevant of file extension)"--- So does that mean whether the extension is `.exe` or `.dll` doesn't matter? It's that flag in the header that truly distinguishes them....So if I make an `exe` and name it via GUI interaction as a `.dll`, but then change that flag manually, it's still runnable?

Answer (score 6):

Dll v/s Exe

1)DLL file is a dynamic link library which can be used in exe files and 
other dll files.
  EXE file is a executable file which runs in a separate 
process which is managed by OS.

2)DLLs are not directly executable . They are separate files containing functions that can be called by programs and other DLLs to perform computations and functions.
 An EXE is a program that can be executed . Ex :Windows program

3)Reusability
DLL: They can be reused for some other application. As long as the coder knows the names and parameters of the functions and procedures in the DLL file .
EXE: Only for specific purpose .

4)A DLL would share the same process and memory space of the calling application while an
 EXE creates its separate process and memory space.

5)Uses
DLL: You want many applications to use it but you don't want to give them the source code You can't copy-paste the code for the button in every program, so you decide you want to create a DL-Library (DLL).

EXE: When we work with project templates like Windows Forms Applications, Console Applications, WPF Applications and Windows Services they generate an exe assembly when compiled.

6)Similarities :
Both DLL and EXE are binary files have a complex nested structure defined by the Portable Executable format, and they are not intended to be editable by users.

Answer (score 4):

Two things: the extension and the header flag stored in the file.

Both files are PE files.  Both contain the exact same layout.  A DLL is a library and therefore can not be executed.  If you try to run it you'll get an error about a missing entry point.  An EXE is a program that can be executed.  It has an entry point.  A flag inside the PE header indicates which file type it is (irrelevant of file extension).  The PE header has a field where the entry point for the program resides.  In DLLs it isn't used (or at least not as an entry point).

One minor difference is that in most cases [DLLs](http://www.registryfast.com) have an export section where symbols are exported.  EXEs should never have an export section since they aren't libraries but nothing prevents that from happening.  The Win32 loader doesn't care either way.

Other than that they are identical.  So, in summary, EXEs are executable programs while DLLs are libraries loaded into a process and contain some sort of useful functionality like security, database access or something.

Comment: +1: So few people realize that technically, the difference is only one bit in the PE header

Comment: I wonder what would happen in an interview if you answered that way.
Them: "What's the difference between a DLL and an EXE?" You: "One Bit".

Answer (score 3):

An EXE is visible to the system as a regular Win32 executable. Its entry
point refers to a small loader which initializes the .NET runtime and tells
it to load and execute the assembly contained in the EXE.
A DLL is visible to the system as a Win32 DLL but most likely without any
entry points. The .NET runtime stores information about the contained
assembly in its own header.

> dll is a collection of reusable
>   functions where as an .exe is an
>   executable which may call these
>   functions

Comment: The .NET runtime has nothing to do with .exe or .dll, they are binary machine code files (If those are produced in some programming language which is using .NET runtime, then .NET runtime is involved, but that's already responsibility of the exe code itself, not OS loader).

Answer (score 3):

The .exe is the program. The .dll is a library that a .exe (or another .dll) may call into.

What sakthivignesh says can be true in that one .exe can use another as if it were a library, and this is done (for example) with some COM components. In this case, the "slave" .exe is a separate program (strictly speaking, a separate process - perhaps running on a separate machine), but one that accepts and handles requests from other programs/components/whatever.

However, if you just pick a random .exe and .dll from a folder in your Program Files, odds are that COM isn't relevant - they are just a program and its dynamically-linked libraries.

Using Win32 APIs, a program can load and use a DLL using the LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress API functions, IIRC. There were similar functions in Win16.

COM is in many ways an evolution of the DLL idea, originally concieved as the basis for OLE2, whereas .NET is the descendant of COM. DLLs have been around since Windows 1, IIRC. They were originally a way of sharing binary code (particularly system APIs) between multiple running programs in order to minimise memory use.

Answer (score 2):

An exe is an executible program whereas A DLL is a file that can be loaded and executed by programs dynamically.

Comment: Someone probably felt that your answer was not detailed enough.

Comment: yea, people might not know what an executable program is, and that becomes a whole new question itself.

Answer (score 1):

● .exe and dll are the compiled version of c# code which are also called as
assemblies.

● .exe is a stand alone executable file, which means it can executed directly.

● .dll is a reusable component which cannot be executed directly and it requires
other programs to execute it.

Answer (score 1):

For those looking a concise answer,

- If an [assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59068988/4990642) is compiled as a class library and provides types for other assemblies to use, then it has the ifle extension **`.dll`** (dynamic link library), and it cannot be executed standalone.
- Likewise, if an [assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59068988/4990642) is compiled as an application, then it has the file extension **`.exe`** (executable) and can be executed standalone. Before .NET Core 3.0, console apps were compiled to .dll fles and had to be executed by the dotnet run command or a host executable. - [Source](https://books.google.com/books?id=Qzm8DwAAQBAJ&pg=PA228#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Answer (score 0):

### Difference in DLL and EXE:

1) DLL is an In-Process Component which means running in the same memory space as the client process. EXE is an Out-Process Component which means it runs in its own separate memory space.

2) The DLL contains functions and procedures that other programs can use (promotes reuability) while EXE cannot be shared with other programs.

3) DLL cannot be directly executed as they're designed to be loaded and run by other programs. EXE is a program that is executed directly.

Answer (score -2):

The major exact difference between DLL and EXE that DLL hasn't got an entry point and EXE does. If you are familiar with c++ you can see that build EXE has main() entry function and DLL doesn't :)

Comment: Don't think so. Look here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682596(VS.85).aspx