# What exactly is an Assembly in C# or .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, assemblies

Could you please explain what is an Assembly in C# or .NET?

1. Where does it begin and where does it end?
2. What important information should I know about Assemblies?

Comment: Strictly speaking, isn't an assembly a .NET concept rather than a C# concept?

Comment: @JeffH: when I asked the question I thought it was a C# concept. Now I understand it's a .NET one. Nevertheless, since I think other people may be confused like I was, I intentionally did not change it for Google to accommodate for this mistake...

Comment: It's a C# concept as well. You have to understand it to use "internal" access modifier properly.

Comment: My grain of salt: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54803483/7389293

Answer (score 163, accepted):

An assembly is the compiled output of your code, typically a DLL, but your EXE is also an assembly. It's the smallest unit of deployment for any .NET project.

The assembly typically contains .NET code in MSIL (Microsoft Intermediate language) that will be compiled to native code ("JITted" - compiled by the Just-In-Time compiler) the first time it is executed on a given machine. That compiled code will also be stored in the assembly and reused on subsequent calls.

The assembly can also contain resources like icons, bitmaps, string tables and so on. Furthermore, the assembly also contains metadata in the assembly manifest - information like version number, strong name, culture, referenced assemblies and so forth.

In 99% of your cases, one assembly equals a physical file on disk - the case of a multi-file assembly (one assembly, distributed across more than a single file) appears to be a rather odd-ball edge case which I've never encountered so far in my 5+ years of .NET development.

In a multifile assembly there would still be only one assembly manifest in a DLL or EXE and the MSIL code in multiple netmodule files.

Comment: @marc_s: I think you mean a multi-assembly file.  It's possible to package multiple assemblies within a single file via studio's command-line tools, but not directly via the IDE.

Comment: A very important thing in an assembly is the metadata in the assembly manifest. The manifest has information like version, strong name, culture, referenced assemblies etc. In a multifile assembly there would still be only one assembly manifest in a dll or exe and the MSIL code in multiple .netmodule files. Basically an assembly is minimum unit of deployment in >net

Comment: @marc_s: I would appreciate it if you add @Pratik's point to the answer, thanks

Comment: @rax: done; @pratik: now you're confusing me: you talk about "multi-file assembly" again, while @GregD mentioned it really was a "multi-assembly file" - what is it now?? (as I said - I've never encountered such a beast, so I'm a bit unclear whether it's multiple assemblies per file, or multiple files per assembly....)

Comment: @GregD: it seems to be "multi-file assembly" after all - check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/226t7yxe.aspx

Comment: "That compiled code will also be stored in the assembly and reused on subsequent calls."  This is misleading and/or not very clear.  No compiled code is "stored" in an assembly.  I think you may be referring to the way each method/function is "jitted" to native code when it is first called.  Then, while the assembly is in memory, the native code version of the method is called.  If the assembly is unloaded, and later reloaded, the jit process will occur all over again.  Of course this assumes that you are not using NGEN to pre-compile your assemblies to native code (not recommended).

Answer (score 22):

***The answer is in order for immediate-grasping.***

> Put simply, it is the compiled project involving your classes and additional files, if there are. That is, each project in a
> solution is *assembly*.

Or more techinally,

> An *assembly* is where a type is stored in the flesystem. Assemblies are
> a mechanism for deploying code. For example, the *`System.Data.dll`*
> assembly contains types for managing data. To use types in other
> assemblies, they must be referenced. - [Source](https://www.packtpub.com/product/c-12-and-net-8-modern-cross-platform-development-fundamentals-eighth-edition/9781837635870)

How do we know it? If you glance at properties of a *project* under the *solution* you can see the following images.

When you compile the project, it turns out to *DLL* or *EXE*.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Is there a way to locate the actual assembly file from within the IDE? I know it can be located from the Windows Explorer, in the bin folder inside the project, but this is an unpractical way of finding the files.

Comment: @carloswm85 why don't you simply right click and lovate its folder? https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzsRB.png

Comment: not the solution I'm looking for. I don't want to have to access to the Windows Explorer. I found a solution, though. From inside VS19: In `Solution Explorer` click `Show All Files` menu button, then the `bin` folder (and others) will appear. Open `debug` folder, right click on the desired assembly and click `Copy Path`.

Answer (score 15):

[.NET assembly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.net_assembly)

> In the Microsoft .NET framework, an
>   assembly is a partially compiled code
>   library for use in deployment,
>   versioning and security.

Answer (score 10):

http://www.codeguru.com/columns/csharp_learning/article.php/c5845

An assembly is a file that is automatically generated by the compiler upon successful compilation of every .NET application. It can be either a Dynamic Link Library or an executable file. It is generated only once for an application and upon each subsequent compilation the assembly gets updated.

Comment: Assemblies are distinct from the files that contain them.

Comment: @Raghav - Update your photograph with something casual for heavens sake! We're not posing here for passports, you know!

Answer (score 5):

[Here's](http://www.shrinkrays.net/articles/inside-dotnet-assemblies.aspx) another explanation of the make up of .NET Assemblies, a mini-quote:

> The .NET framework consists of the
>   concepts of modules, assemblies, which
>   both store metadata and manifest
>   information. An assembly can contain
>   multiple modules. Visual C# only ever
>   creates one module which is turned
>   into an assembly by the C# compiler
>   (csc.exe), but an assembly can link
>   many .NET modules together via the
>   assembly linker (al.exe) command-line
>   tool. For example each of your source
>   code .cs files could be compiled into
>   a module and linked together to form
>   an assembly - an assembly is just a
>   collection of modules and resources.
>   One of these modules, however; must
>   contain manifest metadata (see below)
>   information for the assembly to be
>   understood by the CLR.
>   ....
>   Having created a new .exe or .dll
>   inside VS.NET you see your file appear
>   inside your bin folder. Opening it in
>   notepad will give out gibberish, or
>   even inside a hexadecimal editor
>   without knowing the structure of the
>   file, you need a tool like ildasm.exe
>   or CFF explorer to make meaning from
>   it. The structure of the assembly is
>   as follows:
>
> PE header
>   CLR header
>   CLR metadata
>   CLR
>   IL code
>   Native data

Comment: Where the hell is that link taking me to? Kind of infinite redirects! After a few redirects it took me to a page that says [this](https://m.imgur.com/a/7g1TrTD). No way to get original the URL you posted either.

Answer (score 2):

When a source code is compiled by the language compiler it Generate a **Managed Assembly** and MSIL(MisroSoft Intermediate Language). That Assembly contains **.dll or .exe file**. An Assebmly can be of two types **Private Assembly** and **Shared Assembly**, shared Assembly is stored in **GAC(Global Assembly Cache)** so that any application can refer to it while private assembly is stored in application folder which can be used by only one Application.

Answer (score 0):

An assembly is a DLL or an EXE which will be created when you publish it or compile your application.

Answer (score 0):

After writing source code of your program(project) then a file is created which may be DLL or EXE depends on your project. It makes only once for a single project. It has two types 
1:- single 
2:- shared or multiprogram
single assembly used only in a single program while shared can be used for multiprogram

Comment: _After writing source code of your program(project) then a file is created which may be DLL or EXE depends on your project_ - after writing the source code? Doesn't seem to be a very good indication as to _when_ that file is created, which BTW is immaterial given the question.

Answer (score 0):

An Assembly is a collection of logical units. Logical units refer to the types and resources which are required to build an application and deploy them using the .Net framework. Basically, Assembly is a collection of Exe and DLLs. It is portable and executable.

Answer (score 0):

Assemblies are a collection of different files created by CSC (C# compiler) whenever you compile a '.cs' file. If the .cs file contained a main method, .exe (executable) would be part of that assembly, else .dll (dynamically linked library) is part of that assembly. Apart from .exe/.dll, assemblies contain the manifest file (metadata of the assembly), resource namespaces (contain language-specific code alterations, for eg. resource files for French, Arabic, etc.), satellite files (separate assembly files for a culture/language). These assembly code files are written in MSIL (Microsoft Intermediate Language), an intermediate code similar to a Java bytecode.