# .net core 2.1 can't reference automapper in startup.cs

Tags: .net-core, automapper

In my nugent panel, I installed

AutoMapper v7.0.1
AutoMapper.extensions.microsoft.dependencyinjection v5.0.1

In my Startup.cs,

I added

Services.AddAutoMapper();

but the compiler gives

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1061  'IServiceCollection' does not contain a definition for 'AddAutoMapper' and no accessible extension method 'AddAutoMapper' accepting a first argument of type 'IServiceCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  OPEApiService   J:\Projects\OPEApiService\OPEApiService\Startup.cs  58  Active
```

I tried clean, rebuild, close and reopen VS.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Hello I have the same error.Did u solve it?

Comment: duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50411188/trying-to-add-automapper-to-asp-net-core-2][1]

Comment: There is a duplicate item answered below: [Trying to add AutoMapper to Asp.net Core 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50411188/trying-to-add-automapper-to-asp-net-core-2)

Answer (score 8):

This could be a compatibility issue between the two packages.
If you have both the AutoMapper and AutoMapper.extensions.microsoft.dependencyinjection packages installed, remove them and add only the AutoMapper.extensions.microsoft.dependencyinjection. It has a dependency on the AutoMapper package.

I had this same issue and was able to resolve it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a reference to :

```
$ AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection
```

Search it using NuGet Packages Manager and install it.

Answer (score 1):

You missed the restore step. From the root directory where the solution file exists, run following command:

```
dotnet clean
dotnet restore
dotnet build
```

Build error I received after including the `services.AddAutoMapper()`;

[image: Build error]

Then after executing the series of command, got it running.

[image: Success]