# what is the meaning of a .dll file in windows....? and what is the meaning of a .so file in linux?

Tags: python, windows, linux, shell

I know both are executable up to my knowledge... But what is the difference between a .dll file and .exe file, and what is the difference between a .so file and a .sh/.py/.bin file?

Comment: Neither are typically considered executables, `.dll`, and `.so` are [shared libraries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_(computing)#Shared_libraries), which can be used by other applications to gain access to some functionality.

Comment: [Difference between .dll and .exe?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1210873/478288)

Comment: And here I thought this question would be an interesting one, like "what is the difference between a .dll and a .so?"...

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams - if only.

Answer (score 0):

`.dll` - Dynamic Linked Library. Its the Microsoft's implementation of shared library which are loaded during program initialization or during execution. Unlike statically linked library it doesn't bloat the code but a single memory image can be shared across multiple different process image. These are not-standalone but requires to be called from an executable. As its a library there can be multiple entry points contrasting to an executable.

`.exe` - A Microsoft implementation of a standalone executable. An executable can be directly loaded as a process by a loader into the memory. There is one and only one entry point which is executed as the first thread of execution.

`.so` - Shared Object. On *nix systems, shared libraries (like dll) are implemented as shared objects.