# information about .so files

Tags: c, linux, unix, shared-libraries

I am new in C programing.I have no Idea about .so files. what is the need of it ? how can I create it ? how to bind my C code or Binary with it ? If I don't make any .so file and directly make executable binary of C code what are the PROS and CONS of it ? need a detail description of it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`.so` files are shared objects. Usually shared libraries are made as `.so`.

By making a library a `.so` you achieve efficiency in memory usage. i.e. when multiple applications which use the library are running, the library is loaded into the memory only once as opposed to the case of static libraries.

Creation of dynamic library:

```
gcc -Wall -fPIC -c *.c
gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,libctest.so.1 -o libctest.so.1.0   *.o
```

`-fPIC`: Compiler directive to output position independent code, a characteristic required by shared libraries.

`-shared`: Produce a shared object which can then be linked with other objects to form an executable.

**You can find more information [here](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LibraryArchives-StaticAndDynamic.html).**

Comment: I have done some steps as the link said but ...in this command :ln -sf /opt/lib/libctest.so.1.0 /opt/lib/libctest.so.1
ln: accessing `/opt/lib/libctest.so.1': Not a directory

Comment: Did mv libctest.so.1.0 /opt/lib command execute properly? Do you find your library in /opt/lib folder ?

Comment: If you look at the libraries in /lib/ and /usr/lib/ you will find both methodologies present. It means these file should be present on /lib dir ? bt they are not . they present only in   /opt/lib dir

Comment: when you are linking your program use additional option in command as gcc -L/opt/lib <rest of the command>

Comment: now I get It. But still can't find PROS and CONS why should I use it ? What It makes me beneficial instead of simple  gcc & ./a.out ?

Comment: As i already mentioned in the answer it loads into the memory only once. Which avoids redundant loading of the same library. Look at the following links.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/140061/when-to-use-dynamic-vs-static-libraries             http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2649334/difference-between-static-and-shared-libraries  http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/gccintro_25.html

Answer (score 1):

`.so` stands for Shared Object. In Windows world, this is known as DLL.

You can use it pretty much the same way as DLLs are used - you can link your application dynamically to it.

If your library is called libblah.so, you can link to it using gcc like this:

```
gcc myprog.c -lblah -o myprog
```

Shared libraries are useful to factor out common functionality into separate files.

However, using shared libraries can lead to phenomenon known as [DLL Hell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLL_Hell). While this problem originated in Windows world, it can be applicable in Linux systems as well, unless you pay very close attention to exact version of shared library used and enforce strict versioning. For example, it is typical that if you compile your application using shared libraries (even system shared libraries, not the ones you have created), and then you try to run the same executable on another Linux box (with substantially different Linux version or distro), it may fail to run - because shared libraries used are not the same.

So, if you want your executable be portable to maximum number of Linux systems without recompilation, it may make sense to compile it statically. While this makes your executable bigger, it does reduce problems typically attributed to DLL Hell.

Answer (score 0):

In addition of the other answers, notice that to build a shared object (or shared library) you'll better compile the relevant source files in [position independent code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code) mode like

```
   gcc -Wall -O -fPIC src.c -c -o src.pic.o
```

<sup>It is always useful to ask for all warnings with `-Wall` when compiling some source code.</sup>

then you can link all these `*.pic.o` files into a `.so` using

```
   gcc -shared src1.pic.o src2.pic.o -o shared.so
```

and you can even link some shared library `libfoo.so` into that shared object using

```
   gcc -shared src1.pic.o src2.pic.o -lfoo -o shared.so
```

At last shared objects can be dynamically loaded into a process using [dlopen](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/dlopen.3.html); this is useful to get [plugins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plugins). (and then define a convention for them and get important symbols in them using `dlsym`)

See also the [program library howto](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/) and the [Executable & Link Format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) & [shared library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_library) wikipages

When make your shared library, better name it `lib`*foo*`.so` where *foo* is some arbitrary name. Then, at link time, use also the `-L` option to `gcc` (actually to the linker) to tell about the directory containing it, and link it using `-l`*foo*  option. For example, name your library `libnewbie.so` when making it, and pass `-L.` (if it is in the current directory) before `-lnewbie` when linking it, e.g. `gcc -Wall myprog.c -L. -lnewbie -o myprog`