# Static linking OpenCV CUDA application errors on external symbol

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv, cuda, linker

Hi I am trying to compile a OpenCV (2.6.4) CUDA program on my Win7 Visual Studio, using static link in order to allow the program to run on another computer without CUDA/OpenCV installed. I think i got pretty close but I get stuck in these errors:

```
1>opencv_core246.lib(gpumat.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _nppiSet_8s_C1R
1>opencv_core246.lib(gpumat.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _nppiSet_8s_C2R
1>opencv_core246.lib(gpumat.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _nppiSet_8s_C3R
1>opencv_core246.lib(gpumat.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _nppiSet_8s_C4R
1>opencv_core246.lib(gpumat.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _nppiSet_8u_C1R
1>opencv_core246.lib(gpumat.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _nppiSet_8u_C4R
1>opencv_core246.lib(gpumat.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _nppiSet_16u_C1R
1>opencv_core246.lib(gpumat.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _nppiSet_16u_C2R
1>opencv_core246.lib(gpumat.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _nppiSet_16u_C4R
1>opencv_core246.lib(gpumat.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _nppiSet_16s_C1R
1>opencv_core246.lib(gpumat.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _nppiSet_16s_C2R
1>opencv_core246.lib(gpumat.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _nppiSet_16s_C4R
1>opencv_core246.lib(gpumat.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _nppiSet_32s_C1R
1>opencv_core246.lib(gpumat.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _nppiSet_32s_C4R
1>opencv_core246.lib(gpumat.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _nppiSet_32f_C1R
1>opencv_core246.lib(gpumat.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _nppiSet_32f_C4R
1>opencv_core246.lib(gpumat.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _nppiSet_8u_C1MR
1>opencv_core246.lib(gpumat.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _nppiSet_8u_C4MR
1>opencv_core246.lib(gpumat.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _nppiSet_16u_C1MR
1>opencv_core246.lib(gpumat.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _nppiSet_16u_C4MR
1>opencv_core246.lib(gpumat.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _nppiSet_16s_C1MR
1>opencv_core246.lib(gpumat.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _nppiSet_16s_C4MR
1>opencv_core246.lib(gpumat.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _nppiSet_32s_C1MR
1>opencv_core246.lib(gpumat.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _nppiSet_32s_C4MR
1>opencv_core246.lib(gpumat.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _nppiSet_32f_C1MR
1>opencv_core246.lib(gpumat.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _nppiSet_32f_C4MR
1>opencv_core246.lib(gpumat.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _nppiCopy_8u_C1MR
1>opencv_core246.lib(gpumat.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _nppiCopy_8u_C3MR
1>opencv_core246.lib(gpumat.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _nppiCopy_8u_C4MR
1>opencv_core246.lib(gpumat.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _nppiCopy_16u_C1MR
1>opencv_core246.lib(gpumat.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _nppiCopy_16u_C3MR
1>opencv_core246.lib(gpumat.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _nppiCopy_16u_C4MR
1>opencv_core246.lib(gpumat.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _nppiCopy_16s_C1MR
1>opencv_core246.lib(gpumat.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _nppiCopy_16s_C3MR
1>opencv_core246.lib(gpumat.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _nppiCopy_16s_C4MR
1>opencv_core246.lib(gpumat.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _nppiCopy_32s_C1MR
1>opencv_core246.lib(gpumat.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _nppiCopy_32s_C3MR
1>opencv_core246.lib(gpumat.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _nppiCopy_32s_C4MR
1>opencv_core246.lib(gpumat.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _nppiCopy_32f_C1MR
1>opencv_core246.lib(gpumat.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _nppiCopy_32f_C3MR
1>opencv_core246.lib(gpumat.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _nppiCopy_32f_C4MR
1>opencv_core246.lib(gpumat.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _nppiConvert_8u16u_C1R
1>opencv_core246.lib(gpumat.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _nppiConvert_8u16u_C4R
1>opencv_core246.lib(gpumat.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _nppiConvert_8u16s_C1R
1>opencv_core246.lib(gpumat.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _nppiConvert_8u16s_C4R
1>opencv_core246.lib(gpumat.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _nppiConvert_8u32f_C1R
1>opencv_core246.lib(gpumat.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _nppiConvert_16u32s_C1R
1>opencv_core246.lib(gpumat.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _nppiConvert_16u32f_C1R
1>opencv_core246.lib(gpumat.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _nppiConvert_16s32s_C1R
1>opencv_core246.lib(gpumat.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _nppiConvert_16s32f_C1R
1>opencv_core246.lib(gpumat.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _nppiConvert_16u8u_C1R
1>opencv_core246.lib(gpumat.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _nppiConvert_16u8u_C4R
1>opencv_core246.lib(gpumat.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _nppiConvert_16s8u_C1R
1>opencv_core246.lib(gpumat.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _nppiConvert_16s8u_C4R
1>opencv_core246.lib(gpumat.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _nppiConvert_32f8u_C1R
1>opencv_core246.lib(gpumat.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _nppiConvert_32f16u_C1R
1>opencv_core246.lib(gpumat.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _nppiConvert_32f16s_C1R
```

Here's what I did so far. Compiled OpenCV with:

WITH_CUDA = ON, BUILD_SHARED_LIBS = OFF

I ran opencv_test_gpu and confirmed my OpenCV was built with CUDA support. I also ensure static libs are built instead of dynamic libs, judging from the *.lib file size and simple compilation test. On the VS 2012 side:

Include Directory = C:\opencv_built\install\include, Runtime Library = /MT, Library directory = C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v5.5\lib\Win32;C:\opencv_built\install\share\OpenCV\3rdparty\lib;C:\opencv_built\install\lib; Additional Dependencies: cudart_static.lib;opencv_calib3d246.lib;opencv_contrib246.lib;opencv_core246.lib;opencv_features2d246.lib;opencv_flann246.lib;libtiff.lib;libpng.lib;libjpeg.lib;libjasper.lib;IlmImf.lib;zlib.lib;opencv_highgui246.lib;opencv_imgproc246.lib;opencv_legacy246.lib;opencv_ml246.lib;opencv_nonfree246.lib;opencv_objdetect246.lib;opencv_photo246.lib;opencv_stitching246.lib;opencv_ts246.lib;opencv_video246.lib;opencv_videostab246.lib;Vfw32.Lib;comctl32.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies).

Can anyone please share some insight where did it went wrong?

Comment: Try adding `npp.lib` to your libraries in additional dependencies, like this:  `cudart_static.lib;npp.lib;opencv_calib3d246.lib;...`

Comment: Hi I just tried that minutes ago, but I tried it with nppc.lib, nppi.lib, npps.lib because I don't have npp.lib in the folder. The solution compiles now, but are those libraries static ones? As I don't have a machine to test now, I am unsure whether will the executable run on another machine without OpenCV/CUDA.

Comment: [Typically in windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/140061/when-to-use-dynamic-vs-static-libraries) shared libraries are using the filename extension `.dll` whereas static libraries are using the filename extension `.lib`  So, yes, those libraries ending in `.lib` are static.  And yes, those libraries (nppc.lib, nppi.lib, npps.lib) are the correct ones to link in.  I was looking at an older version of CUDA toolit when I mentioned npp.lib

Comment: Hi I just moved the exe to another computer but unfortunately I got an error launching the exe. About nppi32_55.dll is missing

Comment: @RobertCrovella, typically, `.dll`s are also used via `.lib`s. The `.lib`s are then called import libraries and contain stubs for the functions in the corresponding `.dll`.

Comment: Yes, agreed, I wasn't very clear.  Any static library in windows is usually ending in `.lib`  Any shared library will usually have a `.dll` component somewhere.  When a dll gets built, however, both a static (.lib) and dynamic (.dll) component get created.    Anyway I think the correct answer in this case is that you cannot create (currently) a fully static version of the npp library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe it's possible (currently, with CUDA 5.5) to build a fully statically-linked application using the npp library.  That is because a portion of the library is delivered via a dll component. Read section 15.4 [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-best-practices-guide/#distributing-cuda-runtime-and-libraries)

In fact, this was not possible at all with CUDA until recently (CUDA 5.5) when [a fully statically linkable CUDA runtime library was delivered](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-toolkit-release-notes/index.html#cuda-compiler-5-5).  So ordinary CUDA applications can be created which don't require additional CUDA dll's to run.  However, AFAIK, the libraries (e.g. CUBLAS, CUFFT, CUSPARSE, NPP) all have dll components, and don't offer a fully static version of the library to link against.

**EDIT:** As newer CUDA versions have been released, some CUDA libraries have incorporated static library/link options.  As of CUDA 9.1, the basic CUDA runtime library (libcudart) has a static option (`libcudart_static`, which is now the default option for `nvcc` compilation), as do CUFFT (`libcufft_static`), CUBLAS (`libcublas_static`), CUSPARSE, CUSOLVER, and NVGRAPH.  As of CUDA 9.0/9.1, the NPP libraries have been split into a [variety of sub-libraries](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/npp/index.html), but these are all available in static versions as well.